# How to prepare async data?

Tags: angular

I have async data that I display in template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let application of (applicationService.applications | async)"></div>
```

The `application` object has property workers: `[{id: 1, name: "O"}]`

Also I have service `WorkerService`. I need to create for each aplication own instance `WorkerService` then to use it in template like:

```
<div *ngFor="let application of (applicationService.applications | async)">
      <div *ngFor="let workers of application.workerService.get()"></div>
 </div>
```

How to do that properly?

**My solution is:**

```
class Application {
   private application: Application;

   constrcutor(public application, public workerService: WorkerService) {
        this.workerService(this.application.workers);
   }

    getWorkers() {
       return workerService.get();
    }

}
```

**Then map it:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
    loadApplication(): Observable<any> {
        return request.get().pipe(map(application) => new Application(application, this.workerService)));
    }
}
```

**Then to use in template:**

```
 <div *ngFor="let application of (applicationService.loadApplication() | async)">
     <div *ngFor="let workers of appliction.getWorkers()"></div>
  </div>
```

I dislike that `ApplicationService` depends on `WorkerService`, because it requires
`Application(application, this.workerService)` in map response.

Could you say, how to to that more correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular lets you define the scope for services. If you want to declare the service at the component scope, you can just declare the service in the providers array of the component. There is good documentation on the [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components) Like this -

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    providers: [
        myService
    ]
})
export class myComponent {
    ...
}
```

This way, each component instance will get a separate instance of the service.

With respect to choosing between separate service instances or a single instance for the entire application, it purely depends on what you need.

If your service will contain state data that pertains only to that component and is not required by other components and you would like to clear that state data when the component is destroyed, then you can declare it at the component scope. This way there is a clear boundary between multiple component instances.

On the other hand, if your application has to maintain the state of all the components in a single place and the components need to interact with each other in order to work, then you could declare it at the module scope. This way all components will have access to one single instance of the service and the service can manage the state for all the components.

Comment: I got you, my proplem is to manage one property `application.workers`  for each loop iteration. To be able add remove and store statement. How to do that?

Comment: Now I have response as `applicationService.applications` it is just array of objects. So, I need to manage property `application.workers`. Should I map it to custom class ExecutorClass?

Comment: Did you get my opinion?

Comment: Can you provide the application service in module scope (so that it is available and common to all instances of the applications) and the worker service in the individual component scope so it is separate for each application component?